# How to get UV for the generated grid in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I make the surface defined by two curves. How to get UV output for this mesh?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use capture attribute to get original positions:

[image]

Adding 0.5 makes coordinates range from 0 to 1, perfect for UV

2. Set output to new attribute in modifier:

[image]

3. Use attribute node to get this generated UV:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The Mesh Grid contains a default UV. You can use it by getting the 'uv_map' attribute.

[image]

[image]

You can also calculate the uv using the vertex index and X & Y count.  You can use this with any deformed grid.

[image]

[image]