# how to keep the original material after using simulation zone in GN?

Tags: geometry-nodes

After changing the geometry in a simulation zone, my whole material is "gone". Does anybody know how to get it "back"?

Comment: This is a limitation of 4.0... I think 4.1 will keep material IDs. Jacques Lucke explains it here https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/108410

Comment: But you've material index that can be captured (never tested it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the fact the material index is preserved and reapply the materials this way:

[image]

A complete example:

[image]

I don't know if a visualization is needed here:

[image]

Comment: Do you know why reassigning the index is needed? Because material index is still there it seems after "join geometry".

Comment: @lemon for the same reason capturing it is needed - it changes upon joining geometry. Since the original geometry is first, I used the reassignment to set the materials of the old geometry.

Comment: ok, got it, for the same reason you could sample (after joining) instead of capturing at the condition the original is first when joined. Thanks

Comment: well... not so clear in fact, material index is available here, but lost by joining? https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDsXk.png however these indices are ok for both original and simulated before joining... strange, don't you think?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady
I see this is the answer to half of my question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/312142/geo-nodes-delete-animated-instances-permanently

Now I'm wondering if you might have any clue as to the other half, on how I am supposed to maintain animation through a sim zone. I think my basic setup is wrong?

Comment: @lemon the materials are discarded in the simulation zones due to problem with retaining references. So simple "primitive" values are kept, like the material index, but references to other datablocks like materials, aren't. "Join geometry" node works similarly (see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/297876/60486) ) to manual joining in the viewport: it adds faces to the first object from other objects, reads materials of those faces, and if a material didn't exist on the first object...

Comment: ... , it adds it and assigns the next available material index. If the material did exist, it uses its mat index. Either way material indices are recalculated. This is why you need to capture it.

Comment: Though... material index is available for both, the original and the simulated one... but never mind, this will be ok for mat ID in 4.1...