# Geonodes: How to Set Material for every material in this remeshed mesh?

Tags: geometry-nodes, remesh

I went through a tutorial to create this blocked mesh similar to remesh > block. But I'm not sure how I can get it to work with multiple materials? I'm not sure how to use the Set Material node for "N" amount of materials. Like I would like to know how I can automatically do a Set Material for every material used in the mesh. In this example I have 3 materials but Set Material only allows me to specify 1 material.

This is my blender file https://blend-exchange.com/b/9dePOe2n

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Before your *Set Material* node, there probably isn't any material on your mesh (because of *Mesh to Volume* and *Volume to Mesh* conversion). Then after that, each *Set Material* is similar to adding a new material slot. Last *Set Material* = last material on the list. Hope it clarify some part of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar principle to:

[how to keep the original material after using simulation zone in GN?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/312064/60486)

Except the material index is also not preserved, so you need to sample it from the nearest surface of the original:

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello thank you for your help. was just missing a tiny detail in your setup, by plugging the subtract node to your sample nearest surface `sample position` socket so the voxels all have same texture color

Comment: Hi Markus maybe you know this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314476/why-does-storenamedattributes-vector-type-for-uvmap-not-work-in-place-of-2dvect