# Python generated geonodes setup not behaving the same with the original geonode setup despite being identical

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes, error

I have made a python script using [this amazing addon Node2Python](https://github.com/BrendanParmer/NodeToPython/releases) from the geometry nodes setup I made when I asked about [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314064/how-to-python-print-out-all-voxel-blocks-and-their-corresponding-colors). Shoutout to [lemon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/19156/lemon) thank you so much for your help! The geometry nodes to voxelize worked perfectly. At first when I generated the python script equivalent of the node setup and then executed it, you will see that the setup is exactly the same with the previous setup I have (The blend file is also available in the previous thread)

[image]

But when I apply this python generated setup, the colors output don't match anymore. I compared both the original GN version and the python generated GN version and I don't see any difference yet the output is not right. What's going on? I'm not sure if I reproduced a bug, can anyone confirm?

[image]

**UPDATE**: It looks like a [bug as confirmed by lemon here](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/119258)

When you apply the modifier notice that there is an empty material added. This new empty material is added at the end in the original setup, hence not interfering with the setup. The python-generated node setup however inserts this empty material at index zero and thus disrupting the node setup by shifting all the material indices. So this is definitely a bug because of the inconsistent behavior despite identical GN setups.

[image]

Now the question is, does anyone know of a workaround to this?

Comment: I don't know the reason, but I ran the script again and... it works!

Comment: not totally. I've studied your files, tried with other models etc. And at the end, I've just regenerated the node tree using the script (and this time, it was ok).

Comment: Yes I've seen that also. Do you confirm that regenerating the node tree does the job (and repeatedly)?

Comment: Well.. I'm now unable to open "wtf" file again... Blender crashes each time...

Comment: thank you for helping me out! this is the code https://pastebin.com/tvWrhpBy

Comment: I think there is a bug somewhere (in gn)... If you apply the modifier using the original node tree, it adds a blank material but at the end so that this is not visible. But with the script this blank material is added at the begining... so it's visible... Why? For now I don't know. Just checked this is the same in 4.2.0. Most likely a bug in Blender. I will report that

Comment: FYI, https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/119258

Comment: ok i see the extra material after apply at index 0 when python generated :( thank you for this information! i will try to find a workaround. i added a comment in the ticket, please can you read it. I think you can reopen if you rename the title differently because the referenced issue is complaining about an empty material added, but in our scenario we are not complaining about an empty material but rather about its inconsistent placement so we have no issue about the extra empty material. I created more specific one https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/119269

Comment: We can conclude that the addon somehow inverts the "join geometry" inputs, so that, if volume is first, we have the empty slot first. right? If having at least one mat slot is the way gn is for volume, your workaround works, but the bug is in the addon, I think.

Comment: Yes I verified now and there indeed is a bug in the addon that it interchanged the noodles to Join Geometry causing the empty material to get prepended instead of appended.

Comment: Digging a bit more, I've sent this new ticket: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/119272 (so not sure this is the addon in itself...)

Comment: And I've warned NodeToPython about that: https://github.com/BrendanParmer/NodeToPython/issues/97

Comment: And (last) scurest pointed me to https://docs.blender.org/api/4.1/bpy.types.NodeLink.html#bpy.types.NodeLink.multi_input_sort_id but multi_input_sort_id will be available in 4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible workaround is to add +1 to the material index since blender consistently adds a hidden empty material to index 0. The development team claims it to be expected behavior in [`TICKET-119258`](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/119258) to add a hidden/secret Empty material.

> [Iliya Katushenock](https://projects.blender.org/mod_moder) commented:
>
> Volume have no material. Every time when new mesh is created from
> scratch (not from other mesh) (but from volume without material), its
> matrials list are empty. We can not have empty materials list on mesh
> in geometry nodes, so empty material slot are added. **This is expected behavior**

So I guess this is the "proper" solution?

[image]

**UPDATE**:

The right solution is to swap the noodles going into the Join Geometry node so that the hidden empty material gets added to the end of the materials list, thus not interfering with the node setup.

[image]

Comment: will not always work. check Gordon's answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/314478/184387