# Why does StoreNamedAttribute's Vector Type for UVMap not work in place of 2DVector type?

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, vector

I'm trying to make [this setup](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314021/geonodes-how-to-set-material-for-every-material-in-this-remeshed-mesh/) compatible for version 3.4 but I don't understand why simply switching `2DVector` to `Vector` didn't work when, based on my understanding, `Vector` would just need to ignore the `z` component to make it compatible with `2DVector` and the `UVMap` which uses only `xy` plane. Did I misunderstand? The texture suddenly becomes plain colored when switching to `Vector`.

[image]

Comment: Can you show how you use the attribute *UVMap* in the Shading Editor ? Do you set Z coordinate to 0 ?

Comment: Hi @StefLAncien thanks for your response. Does this one help? I have a blend file here [in this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314386/python-generated-geonodes-setup-not-behaving-the-same-with-the-original-geonode). Just change one of the materials to a texture to see the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

It seems that in the *Shading Editor*, the *UV Map* node is expecting a *2DVector* type, and that if the attribute *UVMap* is a *Vector* (i.e. 3D), it is not identified as a valid *UVMap*. But using an *Attribute* node to recover the named attribute *UVMap* instead of a *UV Map* node seems insensitive to the type, *2DVector* or *Vector*.

**With 2DVector:**
[image: 2DVector setup]

**With Vector:**
[image: Vector setup]

Comment: Sorry, I do not have access to Blender 3.4. I am confused because documentation of version 3.4 is referring to *2D Vector* type already (see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/store_named_attribute.html and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html#attribute-data-types)

Comment: thank you for this post. yes i was looking for a pure geometry nodes solution so i could make it work out of the box without needing to adjust the shaders as well..

Comment: actually both Attribute ndoe and UVMap nodes in the shader tree work in blender 3.4, and I think it is really necessary to specify that to make this work. thank you.